# Stop ExecutorService on thread failure and exception handling

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

This is a simplified example I did to expose my problem. I have some task `doSomeWork()` that I handle in a multihreading fashion using ExecutorService (4 threads at a time max).  However, if any of the threads/tasks generates an exception, I would like to:

1. Stop any further tasks from being processed.
2. Catch the exception at the main thread level.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
       final ExecutorCompletionService<Void> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);

       try {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               int b = i;
                   completionService.submit(() -> doSomeWork(b));
           }

           threadPool.shutdown();
           threadPool.awaitTermination(8, TimeUnit.HOURS);

           System.exit(0);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Something wrong happened: " + e.getMessage());
       }

       System.exit(1);

   }

   //This function have 50% odds of throwing an exception
   public static Void doSomeWork(int i) throws Exception {

       Thread.sleep(500);
       if ((Math.random() > 0.5))
       {
           System.out.println("I have reached indice: " + i);
       }
       else
       {
           throw new Exception("I couldn't handle indice " + i);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

Currently, an execution would output something like this:

```
I have reached indice: 0
I have reached indice: 2
I have reached indice: 1
I have reached indice: 4
I have reached indice: 6
I have reached indice: 7
I have reached indice: 5
I have reached indice: 9
```

As you can see, `indice 3` is missing, nevertheless the execution of the remaining threads completed. It also didn't output anything about the exception.

My desired output would be something like this:

```
I have reached indice: 0
I have reached indice: 2
I have reached indice: 1
Something wrong happened: I couldn't handle indice 3
```

Other solutions I found around this problem were using a callable with a future but in a blocking fashion. I can't block the execution of other threads while waiting for the future otherwise this whole multithreading is pointless.

Comment: Please check your question before posting, and always add all relevant tags.

Comment: The task you submit to the thread pool is encapsulated as a ```FutureTask```,  and any exception that occurs during execution will be caught by the FutureTask#run method, 
 so you need to either catch the exception inside the task or get it from the returned Future#get.

Comment: " I can't block the execution of other threads while waiting for the future ..." using future.get doesn't block the execution of the other threads.  It could be used in the same manner you're using "awaitTermination". It would block the main thread while the other threads are executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using `CompletableFuture`. This is your main function I tested:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
final List<CompletableFuture<Void>> all = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int b = i;
        CompletableFuture<Void> v = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        doSomeWork(b);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                },
                executorService);
        all.add(v);
    }

    CompletableFuture<Void> placeholder = CompletableFuture.allOf(all.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    failFast(all, placeholder);

    System.out.println("All tasks ended");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something wrong happened: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

Utility function to make the joint future fail as soon as one of them is failed (or when all of them are completed):

```
private static <T> void failFast(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures, CompletableFuture<T> joint) {
    while (true) {
        if (joint.isDone()) {
            return;
        }
        for (CompletableFuture<T> future : futures) {
            if (future.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
I have reached indice: 1
I have reached indice: 7
I have reached indice: 5
I have reached indice: 4
Something wrong happened: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: I couldn't handle indice 0
```

Explanation:

The method `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` allows you to provide with a `Runnable` (your `doSomeWork`) and an executor with a certain number of threads. Here, I pass an executor with 4 threads (as you did in your example).

Inside the runnable, I don't only run the `doSomeWork` function but I also catch `Exception` and throw a `RuntimeException` (need to do that because Lambdas do not support checked exceptions, so I need to wrap it into a runtime one but it will still interrupt execution and be catched by your main).

Each time I create a new `CompletableFuture<Void>` for the task with the given index `i`, I will store this result into a list of completable futures.

The for loop will take nothing to execute, since the completable futures run asynchronously.

Hence, I create a joint completable future with `CompletableFuture.allOf(...)` and then I use the utility function `failFast` on this future in order to stop as soon as one of the task is failed (or to continue until all of them are complete).

So basically as soon as one of the futures fails throwing an exception, the joint future is considered to be completed and will hence leave the handle to your main thread which is, meanwhile, being hit by the `RuntimeException` that was thrown inside the lambda expression.

**Note:** thanks to Thomas' comment, I've updated the code to use an `ExecutorService` instead of a simple `Executor`. That allows you to have a call to `shutdownNow()` inside your `finally` block after you catch the exception.
As Thomas suggests, also, you may directly throw a `RuntimeException` inside your `doSomeWork` function so you don't need to catch and wrap inside the lambda expression.

**Other note:** @matt made me notice something I didn't know. The `.allOf()` future will be completed when *ALL* futures are completed, whether successfully or not.
Hence, as he pointed out, my solution wouldn't work as is. I've edited again the answer to take his comment into account, thanks @matt for making me notice.

Comment: I totally forgot about `CompletableFuture`, +1 for that. I'd add 2 things though: 1) `executor` should be of type `ExecutorService` so that you can call `shutdownNow()` in the `finally` block. Otherwise it would keep the application alive. 2) The OP could throw that `RuntimeException` directly if possible which would simplify the lambda - this should just be pointed out.

Comment: @Thomas these are good remarks indeed, thank you. Feel free to edit the answer if you wish, hence I'll add them later after lunch break :)

Comment: I'll let you make the changes in your style. Don't want to mess up your answer :)

Comment: @matt I'm doing it because the lambda cannot throw checked exceptions, it's a known limitation of lambdas. Hence whatever is thrown inside the lambda, must be wrapped into a runtime exception (or a child of it) in order to flow out of the lambda itself. There's no other way of throwing an exception inside a lambda expression unfortunately, but it's still an exception that can be caught and handled.

Comment: @matt the allOf future is a future which is successful when all of them are successful and is failed as soon as one of them is failed. If you have 10 futures inside and one of them is completed exceptionally, there is no need to wait for the other futures - the allOf is already determined to have completed exceptionally.

Comment: You were right @matt, I made a test and indeed I was wrong in what I said above. I've edited my answer accordingly, thanks a lot because you taught me something today.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've excluded a correct way to do this, based on an incorrect assumption. Keep your futures.

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then when you submit.

```
futures.add( completionService.submit( () -> doSomeWork(b) ) );
```

Now, you can check the futures status in your main thread.

```
for(Future<?> f: futures){
    try{
        f.get();
    } catch( ExecutionException e){
        //execution exception handled on the main thread.
        completionService.shutdownNow();
    } catch( InterruptedException ie){
        //what should happen here.
    }
}
```

That way, shutdownNow gets called, so all of the non-started tasks get returned and will not start.

You could use a timeout with `get` to check every task since some will be running in parallel.

Here is a complete compilable example.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ExecutorJunk{
    static int count = 0;
    static void task(){
        int z = count++;
        
        if(z == 3){
            throw new RuntimeException("z is 3");
        }
        
        System.out.println("z: " + z);
        try{ Thread.sleep(1500);} catch(InterruptedException e){};
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        
        List<Future<?>> all = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            all.add( service.submit(ExecutorJunk::task) );
        }
        service.shutdown();
        
        try{
            while(!service.isTerminated()){
                for(Future f: all){
                    try{
                      f.get(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch( TimeoutException toe){
                      //pass.
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println( service.shutdownNow().size() + " tasks not started");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

When I run this I get.

> z: 0
> z: 1
> z: 2
> z: 4
> 5 tasks not started
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: z is 3
> ...

It probably could be done a bit smarter. Such as purging the list of futures as get succeeds, instead of using a timeout just check the futures if they're done, then doing a future.get.

Comment: The problem with this is that you wait for each result synchronously using .get(). It means that you may be waiting the result of task X while task X+4 has already failed and you won't see it before you step forward of 4 elements in your list.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I may be very well making an incorrect assumption. However I have trouble understanding the workflow of the snippets your proposed here. How does exactly the 3 snippet fit in with the rest of the code? I mean how are you able to check the 'future' array periodically before completing execution of all threads? Shouldn't the 3rd snippet be sitting in its own thread for this to work? It would be really helpful if you could provide the full picture here.

Comment: @Mit94 Yes, the 3rd snippet will be sitting on it's "own thread" which happens to be the main thread. It goes in place of your "completionService.awaitTermination".

Comment: @matt sorry, I had missed that. But still, even if you define a timeout, you still rely on a sequential check of each future while the idea is to have them run in parallel (with only limitation being the number of threads per executor) and be notified immediately when a failure occurs so that all the other pending tasks can be shutdown

Comment: @MatteoNNZ what sort of check is allOf performing? It should be documented if it was performing a check.